# Getting main product categories from Amazon Product Advertising API

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-product-api

I am trying to get the list of product categories from Amazon using Amazon Product Advertising API.

The below list has all the node Id for each category across all domains.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/BrowseNodeIDs.html

I am able to get all sub-nodes by passing a Node Id using the below method.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/BrowseNodeLookup.html

But I need to know those list of parent Nodes before that.

How can I get the list of main Nodes for each country separately? Is hardcoding those entire list the only way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shortest and only anwer that I found is that there is no API function to lookup the root browsenodes.